# C and choose between structure

Tags: c, class, structure, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I would like to implement a multi language menu on my micro-controller, but I don't know how.

I thought of some ideas for structure languages who have more sub structure (English, Slovenian, German, ...), and on sub structure have:

```
char title[] = "MENU"; //english
```

But I don't know how access into my structure because in main class I have a function to set language.

Example:

```
function choose language{
      choose language = 1; //english
      //choose language = 2; //slovenian
}
```

Call value from structure

```
PutChar(language[].title);    //before choosing the language 1 English, because now call sub structure English.
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=internationalizing%20c%20embedded

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  What is that pseudocode supposed to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you will have all of your text hardcoded. Simply create an array of strings:

```
const char* const title[] = { "MENU" , "MENI" } ;
```

And then every access to such an object is done via the language enumerator:

```
enum
{
    english = 0 ,
    slovenian = 1 ,
} ;
```

Enums in C are int, so the above code could be done using macro defines, with the same effect:

```
#define english 0 
#define slovenian 1
```

Then you just define your variable language, set a language, and print the values.

```
int language = english ;

puts( title[language] ) ;
language = slovenian ;
puts( title[language] ) ;
```